# An algorithm to check if a number is an Extra Perfect Number (it has the same first and last bits) in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

This may seem obvious, but what is exactly is an extra perfect number? I need to write an algorithm to find extra perfect for a given *n*, from 1 thru *n*. Unfortunately, I can't seem to wrap my mind around the question's wording. These are the examples given:

```
extraPerfect(3)  ==>  return {1,3}
extraPerfect(7)  ==>  return {1,3,5,7}
```

> ### Task:
>
> Given a positive integer N, return the extra perfect numbers in range from 1 to N.
>
> A number is called Extra Perfect Number if it has the same first and last bits (set bits).
>
> #### Notes:
>
> 1. Only positive integers will be passed.
> 2. The returned vector/list should contain the extra perfect numbers in
>    ascending order (from lowest to highest).
>
> #### Example #1
>
> ```
> extraPerfect(3)  ==>  return {1,3}
> ```
>
> **Explanation:**
>
> (1)<sub>10</sub> = (1)<sub>2</sub>
>
> First and last bits as set bits.
>
> (3)<sub>10</sub> = (11)<sub>2</sub>
>
> First and last bits as set bits.
>
> #### Example #2
>
> ```
> extraPerfect(7)  ==>  return {1,3,5,7}
> ```
>
> **Explanation:**
>
> (5)<sub>10</sub> = (101)<sub>2</sub>
>
> First and last bits as set bits.
>
> (7)<sub>10</sub> = (111)<sub>2</sub>
>
> First and last bits as set bits.

Comment: I suggest the following : looping from 1 through n, a function that determines whether or not the number it has been given is an EPN, a function that transforms a number to the only significant bits as a string(1 => "1" not 31 zeros followed by a 1)

Comment: Please post the definition you were given.  "Extra perfect number" is not a common term in number theory.  What little you've given is merely a strange way of describing "odd number", which is a trivial program.

Comment: It sounds like you should followup with your class teacher - based on your example, it looks like the goal is just to find odd numbers, which should be trivial.  Based on [this](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/extra-perfect-numbers/0) link from [Mark_M's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49909976/836214), the definition matches, but your sample output doesn't (7 wouldn't be "extra perfect" by that definition)

Comment: As a further note, this looks like a copy-paste from [here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/extra-perfect-numbers-special-numbers-series-number-7)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that an extra perfect number is simply an ***odd*** number as, in base 2, it will always start and end with a 1, whereas an even number will always start with a 1 but end with a 0.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like *extraPerfect* should return a list of all numbers less than the argument which have the same first and last digit after converting the decimal argument to binary.

For example: 
Decimal - Binary
**1     -     1**
2        -  10
**3       -   11**
4        -  100
**5      -    101**
6        -  110
**7     -     111**

You'll notice the bold values have the same first and last binary digits.


Some pseudo-code might look like:

```
function extraPerfect( n ){
  var perfects = [];

  for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    var binary = toBinary(i);

    if(binary[0] === binary[binary.length]){
      perfects.push(i);
    }
  }

  return perfects;
}
```

You could pull an algorithm form the pseudo-code.

Comment: You might also notice that the bold numbers are all odd, which could suggest a simpler algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

Ah now I see I was wrong because I thought it is all about palindroms. However I hope it can be still helpful. That's the code for palindroms in section between 1 to prompt's value.

```
var exns = (function(){
  function dec2bin(dec){
    return (dec >>> 0).toString(2);
  }
  function isEXN(num){
    var con = dec2bin(num); // 11011 = 3 + 24 = 27
    var accurate = Math.ceil(con.length/2); // 5/2 = 3
    var lenmin = con.length-1;
    for(var i = 0; i < accurate; i++){
      if(con.charAt(i) !== con.charAt(lenmin-i))
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  var max = parseInt(prompt("Numbers from 1 to ...?"));
  var exns = [];
  if(!isNaN(max)){
    for(var i = 1; i<=max; i++){
      if(isEXN(i))
        exns.push(i);
    }
  }
  return exns;
})();
```

Exns should contain array with values.

Answer (score -1):

A Perfect Number is equal to the sum of its positive divisors.

```js
function perfect(num){
  for(var i=1,n=0; i<num; i++){
    if(num % i === 0){
      n += i; 
    } 
  }
  return n === num;
}
console.log(perfect(6));
console.log(perfect(7));
console.log(perfect(28));
console.log(perfect(8127));
console.log(perfect(8128));
```

Comment: OP also asks **"This may seem obvious, but what is exactly is an extra perfect number?"**.